# Joomla Contact form - autofill email and username of logged in user

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

Is it possible to autofill name and email of logged in user in joomla original contacs form or do I have to download some extension to do the work? I can't find anything on google. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: So you want to take the name and the email from the user object?  That's kind of a cool idea.  I think you could do that with a plugin that tests for logged in status, makes the two fields hidden and sets their values equal to the values from the user object.

Comment: Can you be more specific how would you do that? Which plugin I can use for test of login status? And how can I set form field to value of some plugin value?

Comment: You don't need a plugin just get the user object. What research have you done?

Comment: I googled all around the possibility to activate autofill of name of logged user to joomla contact form with no luck. I already know how to access current user object ($user_name = $user->name;) but I don't know how to get this info to joomla contact form, if that is possible.

Comment: Modify the form to set value to $user->name or whatever if the user is logged in.  You might even be able to do that with an override.

Comment: Ok, so I created overrides of com_contact. According to this [stackoverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406593/fill-joomlas-form-field) I tried to add   `<?php $this->form->setValue('jform_contact_name',null,$user->name); ?>` to com_contact->contact->default.php and also to defaul_form.php, but nothing really happened. I must admit that my php skills are really really bad. I'm not even sure if I'm editting the right file. Am I getting closer or am I completely wrong?

Comment: THat's actually a good try ... what do you get if you var_dump($this->form) after that code?

Comment: I've got something like this `object(JForm)#257 (6) { ["data":protected]=> object(Joomla\Registry\Registry)#255 (2) { ["data":protected]=> object(stdClass)#237 (0) { } ["separator"]=> string(1) "." } ["errors":protected]=> array(0) { } ["name":protected]=> string(19) "com_contact.contact" ["options":protected]=> array(1) { ["control"]=> string(5) "jform" } ["xml":protected]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#254 (1) { ["fieldset"]=> array(2) { [0]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#389 (2) { ["@attributes"]=> array(3) { ["name"]=> string(7) "contact" ["addrulepath"]=> string(35) ` Should I look for something?

Comment: I'm sorry right now I don't have time to help you, I would suggest you post on [joomla.se] the joomla stack exchange site.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla includes a "User - Contact Creator" plugin, disabled by default that automatically creates contacts for new users. These can be automatically published or not.

Or maybe you need something more interactive?

[image: Contact Creator Plugin]

Comment: Hi, that's not exactly what I'm trying to do. I want to have contact form on website, but accessible only to registered users. As soos as they log in, the contact form should be accessible to them, but the name and email should be filled in from user information which I already have. But how to do this in joomla is mystery for me.

Some joomla form extensions can do this, but I would rather stick with joomla solution

Answer (score 0):

Just did the same thing using an override for com_contact/contact/default_form.php

Add `$user = JFactory::getUser();` to the php code in the header of the module and add the following lines to the  block in the body of the `<?php foreach ($fields as $field) : ?>` loop before the call to `<?php echo $field->renderField(); ?>`:

```
                    <?php if ($field->name === 'jform[contact_name]' && $user->username) : ?>
                        <?php $field->setValue($user->username); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>             
                    <?php if ($field->name === 'jform[contact_email]' && $user->email) : ?>
                        <?php $field->setValue($user->email); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
```

Example of the full loop for Joomla 3.6.x:

```
                <?php foreach ($fields as $field) : ?>
                    <?php if ($field->name === 'jform[contact_email_copy]' && !$this->params->get('show_email_copy')) : ?>
                        <?php continue; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if ($field->name === 'jform[contact_name]' && $user->username) : ?>
                        <?php $field->setValue($user->username); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>             
                    <?php if ($field->name === 'jform[contact_email]' && $user->email) : ?>
                        <?php $field->setValue($user->email); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>                     
                    <?php echo $field->renderField(); ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

This did at least the trick for me.